# Is the latest Dojo 1.6.1 included in the Google Libraries?

Tags: dojo

When i try to use the statement `google.load("dojo", "1.6.1")` in a web app I am developing, I receive the error:

> Module: 'dojo' with version '1.6.1' not found!

This latest version of dojo, enables a certain amount of support for IE 9.0, and that is why I need to reference it. Is this supported by Google as a library?  Either way, if anyone has suggestions as to how I can work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.6.1 is not yet in the Google ajax library repositories. See the [latest version note here](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#dojo). I'm sure it will be within a day or two. There is a [note on the dojo download page in big red letters](http://dojotoolkit.org/download/) saying that the CDN's are still behind on 1.6.0 and saying where to get notified when they are updated.

You can always use the "1.6" nomenclature to always have the latest version and your app will move up to 1.6.1 as soon as it hits the Google CDN. If a couple days is really going to make or break you you should consider compiling and using your own local version. Dojo [makes this really easy](http://build.dojotoolkit.org/).

Comment: Thank you, i appreciate it.  This is the info i needed.  I will wait, i just hope it Google adds this soon.

Comment: Just to make sure, it does not matter whether i used my own version or not does it?  "google.load("dojo", "1.6.1")" will not work either way with 1.6.1, until the library is accepted by Google.  Is this correct?

Comment: Your last comment doesn't make any sense. If you use your own version you can use any version you like including 1.6.1, but you have to host the files yourself. If you want to use Google's CDN hosted version you can only ask for versions that they have up.